# STFT output frequency does not match sin wave frequency

Tags: frequency, stft

I have the following function and pre definition for producing a sin and its' stft:

```
fs=48000
nfft=2048
hop_len=nfft/2
win_len=2048
nfft = next_greater_power_of_2(win_len)

def sinus_gen(f):
   np.expand_dims(np.sin(2*np.pi*f*np.arange(fs*20)/fs).astype(np.float64)...
    ,axis=1)
```

I am trying to generate and plot an 8KHz using the following stft command:

```
audio=sinus_gen(8000)
s=librosa.core.stft(audio[:, 0], n_fft=nfft, hop_length=hop_len,
                                        win_length=win_len, window='hann')
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(s)),x_axis='time',y_axis='log',cmap='jet')
plt.title('Power spectogram before beamforming')
plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
plt.clim(-60,30)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I am getting the following spectrogram image, which shows 4000KHz for some reason:
[image]

Why am I not seeing the expected 8000KHz frequency? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `sr=fs` as well as `hop_length=hop_length` to the [specshow](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.display.specshow.html) function, as its default values are different from yours.